# Principal ideal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $K$ be a principal ideal ring. How to prove that for any $ x= (x_1, x_2)^t \in K^2 $ there exists a  matrix $G \in SL_2(K)$ such that $Gx = (\gcd(x_1, x_2),0)^t $ ?

Comment: Do you mean greatest common divisor ? Its not quite clear.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Yes.

Comment: Remark that the matrix appears in the bottom right corner of the table constructed by the Extended Euclidean algorithm - [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's the greatest common divisor $d$ of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ you mean, and you assume that $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are not both zero, so that $d \ne 0$, then there are $a, b \in K$ such that $a x_{1} + b x_{2} = d$, and now take
$$
G = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
-x_{2}/d & x_{1}/d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Of course if $x_{1} = x_{2} = 0$, *any* $G$ will do.